# Is it possible to wrap Poppler with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, poppler

It is my hobby project. I want to view pdf documents in my Flutter app.
I want to use Poppler C++ [library](https://github.com/freedesktop/poppler) and wrap it with Flutter using dart ffi.
I just checked the library but can't find any way to start.
Is it possible to wrap it with Flutter? If yes, I need a guideline to start the project.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: He did you achieve a way to do this? Especially to manage to build this app having poppler feature support and make it an executable for e.g. windows/mac?